# How can I boot from a Windows 10 USB stick on a Medion Akoya laptop

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10-upgrade

I put a Windows 10 `de_windows_10_education_version_1511_x86_dvd_7223961.iso` file on a USB stick, using the
[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) tool, in order to repair a failed Windows 10 upgrade.

Subsequently, I inserted this stick in a MEDION Akoya E1318T (MD 99330) laptop.

However, as shown in the below photos, I cannot boot from the USB stick. It does not show up in the boot menu although I am certain that it is bootable.

Can anyone advise me how to proceed?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please check if uefi boot is enabled on your device. x86 installation medias can't be booted with uefi.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wasn't aware that UEFI cannot boot from x86 media. Since the [CPU](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-A-Series-A4-1200-Notebook-Processor.92892.0.html) seems to support 64-bit, I will try a USB boot medium based on `Win10_1511_German_x64.iso`.

Comment: Unfortunately the 64-bit medium does not boot either. What else could I still try?

Comment: you formatted the usb with gpt partition schema right? if not please follow this tutorial : http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-installation

Comment: GPT was a very useful hint. Thank you so much! Now the laptop at least boots from the usb drive but presents me with the following error: `Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We'll restart for you. If you'd like to know more, you can search online later for this error: 0xc000021` As far as I understood from [here](http://appuals.com/best-fix-steps-fix-error-0xc000021a/), I need to disable driver signature enforcement but cannot find a respective option in the BIOS. How do you advise me to proceed? Thankfully!

Comment: Can you try with official windows 10 media creation tool ?  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 . I don't think signature enforcement was the problem here because you aren't trying to boot into a working installation. After you run it, choose create installation for another pc.

Comment: Does the partition of your bootable drive have the ESP flag?